# How to mask System.out.println(CARD_NUMBER) values in catalina.out

Tags: java, log4j

I want to mask the System.out.println(CARD_NUMBER) values in the catalina.out

I have done the following below coding and it is working fine for Logging e.g. Log.info(CARD_NO) gets masked as XXXX , but the same CARD_NO does not gets masked if it is written as System.out.println(CARD_NUMBER) , instead the CARD_NO is printed in catalina.out

In Some class Test e.g

Log.info(CARD_NO)   ---> XXXX (Masked Card no)

System.out.println(CARD_NO)  ---> CARD_NO printed(No Masked Card no)

In Log4j.xml

```
 <log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
        <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
            <param name="Target" value="System.out" />
            <layout class="com.test.soap.common.CustomFilteringLayout">
                <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ISO8601} %-5p %c{1}.%M() %m%n" />
            </layout>
        </appender>

        <appender name="logfile" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
            <param name="File" value="../logs/test.log" />    
            <layout class="com.test.soap.common.CustomFilteringLayout">
                <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ISO8601}{CST} %p %t [%c] - %m%n" />
            </layout>
        </appender> 

       <root>
        <priority value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="logfile" />    
        <appender-ref ref="console" />         
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

CustomFilteringLayout class

```
public class CustomFilteringLayout extends EnhancedPatternLayout {
    /**
     * Any number that's of 10 digit would be masked (e.g: cardId). If number is > 11 digit then first 12 digit would masked.
     * This is so because of keeping it in mind that cardNumber's length is 16 digit so first 12 digit would be masked.
     * 
     * @param LoggingEvent event
     * @return String formated String
     */

    @Override
    public String format(LoggingEvent event) {

        if (event.getMessage() instanceof String) {
            String message = event.getRenderedMessage();

            Matcher matcher = RemoteConstants.PATTERN.matcher(message);
            if (matcher.find()) {

                String maskedMessage ="";
                if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(matcher.group(1))&& matcher.group(1).length()==RemoteConstants.CARD_NUMBER_LENGTH){
                    StringBuffer masked = new StringBuffer();

                    masked.append(matcher.group(1).substring(0, 4)).append(" ");
                    masked.append(matcher.group(1).substring(4, 6)).append("XX ");
                    masked.append("XXXX ").append(matcher.group(1).substring(12, 16));

                    maskedMessage=masked.toString();
                }else{
                    maskedMessage = matcher.replaceAll(RemoteConstants.MASK);
                }

                Throwable throwable = event.getThrowableInformation() != null ? event.getThrowableInformation()
                        .getThrowable() : null;
                LoggingEvent maskedEvent = new LoggingEvent(event.fqnOfCategoryClass, Logger.getLogger(event
                        .getLoggerName()), event.timeStamp, event.getLevel(), maskedMessage, throwable);
                return super.format(maskedEvent);
            }
        }

        return super.format(event);
    }
}
```

Comment: as per your code,  LoggingEvent  will work for logger class, not for System.out.println

Comment: Have you considered not printing it with `System.out.println`? Actually it's a bad practice to use direct console logging in applications, you should use file/network logging with a proper logger (like log4j). Also, if you handle sensitive data it may be appropriate not to print it at all (i.e. you shouldn't ***ever*** try to print/log a credit card number for obvious security issues, and if you need to store it you should make sure that it's properly crypted with a strong algorithm and key).

Comment: Thanks for the valuable advise , but is it not possible to mask the CARD_NUM in System.out.println i.e in catalina.out using the Log4j.xml.    i.e instead of LoggingEvent any other event can help to mask the data of  System.out.println

Comment: @AnkurMehrotra It isn't possible, because log4j acts on logs, not on `System.out`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you any mean to remove all call to System.out.println or to replace them with calls to Logger?

Otherwise, if you *really* cannot correct the original code, have you thought about overriding `System.out` through the use of `System.setOut`? You could set a print that detects that the input string is a card number and mask it - printing the rest normally... ?

Something like :

```
PrintStream underlyingOut = System.out;
System.setOut(new PrintStream(underlyingOut) {
    @Override
    public void println(String x) {
        if(x.matches("[0-9\\-]+")) {
            super.println(x.replaceAll("[0-9]", "X"));
        } else {
            super.println(x);
        }
    }
});

System.out.println("Hello");
System.out.println("123-4567-89");
```

This would slow down System.out.println calls, but it outputs :

```
Hello
XXX-XXXX-XX
```

HTH!